# Memory Question

Tags: memory, cpu, ram, decoder, addressing

Picture of memory bank and questions:

[image]

for b) The CPU should use address 101100 to store A in chip 2 with the location 22. My thought process is that the first bit decides which ram chips will be used. When the first bit is 0 we use ram chips 1 and 2 etc( because of decoder). The other part (10110) will be the location of the letter.

So am I correct or totally wrong?

for c)

If I used 101100 as the address for A then wouldn't B be stored at ram chip 1( since B is stored within data lines d0 - d7) with the same address 1011?

I am on the right track?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are correct, but I can't see for sure which output of the decoder will be active, because it has no lables on its outputs. And I would avoid talking about the 'first' bit (which is open to multiple interpretations), better call it the 'lowest' bit.